# Wamp won't start after installing SSL

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, openssl

I installed SSL using [this guide](http://www.phpjoel.com/2011/04/07/installing-ssl-using-openssl-on-a-wamp-localhost/) but after I finished, I was unable to start up WampServer. I made sure to follow everything correctly in that guide (replacing the paths given in the guide with the ones on my computer).

I looked through my error logs and found nothing from the times I was trying to start the server. When I try to start it using command line with `httpd -d`, I get the error

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 51 of ......./apache2.4.2/conf/extra/httpd_ssl.conf: 
Invalid command 'SSSLCipherSuite', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not
included in the server configuration
```

although I have mod_ssl.so in my modules file.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might follow the article : [Install HTTPS on wamp correctly](https://puvox.software/blog/install-ssl-https-on-wamp-server/)

Answer (score 2):

`SSSLCipherSuite` <-- That's got one too many "S"s on the front.

I'm going to assume that typo is your problem.  If not, make sure the SSL module is enabled and the directives are available (`httpd -L`).
If they aren't you need to load mod_ssl into your server (refer to the [Apache manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_so.html#loadmodule) for information on how to load modules)

Comment: Oh, sorry, that was me making a mistake typing this post. It is correct in the file, I just checked.

Comment: I went through my httpd.conf file and unhashed the include of mod_ssl and then I got another error which suggested I include socache_shmcb_module, so I did and now the site works, except it won't load an http connection, only an https one. Is there any way I can make both work?

Comment: @David you'll have to use virtual hosts to have the two different websites (one with SSL and the other without)

Answer (score 1):

Try to match your configuration with the following lines, these are in my httpd.conf file for the ssl certificate and works fine.

`SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/yourcertificate.crt`

`SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/yourprivatekey.key`

`SSLCertificateChainFile  /etc/pki/tls/certs/yourintermediatecertificate.cer`

Hope that helps.